# WebService con Entity Framework. POST funciona solo con json, no con xml

Tags: json, .net, xml, entity-framework, post

a ver si alguien puede ayudarme.

Estoy montando un webservice con Entity Framework para que desde un cliente realicen una petición POST enviando un XML y este guarde esos datos en una base de datos.

Funciona perfectamente si realizo un POST enviando un json ( utilizando postman ), sin embargo si envío un XML me da error : 400 Bad Request

He puesto un punto de interrupción y los POST con xml se van por el return BadRequest(ModelState);

```
        // POST: api/MT_PalletMovement
    [ResponseType(typeof(MT_PalletMovement))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostMT_PalletMovement(MT_PalletMovement mT_PalletMovement)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.MT_PalletMovement.Add(mT_PalletMovement);

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException)
        {
            if (MT_PalletMovementExists(mT_PalletMovement.OT))
            {
                return Conflict();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = mT_PalletMovement.OT }, mT_PalletMovement);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Necesitas configurar la salida de datos con soporte para XML. 
   Puedes ver un ejemplo completo [**AQUÍ**](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/manas1/introduction-to-Asp-Net-webapi-and-returns-result-in-differe/)

2) Para la entrada de datos en XML puedes procesar el Request manualmente así: 
[image: Entrada de datos]

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using System.Web.Http.Metadata;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace WebApiXmlRequest.Controllers
{
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        // POST api/values
        [ResponseType(typeof(MT_PalletMovement))]
        public IHttpActionResult Post([XmlBody] MT_PalletMovement Model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            // TODO: Lógica de programación que necesites

            return Ok(Model);
        }
    }

    public class MT_PalletMovement
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed class XmlBodyAttribute : ParameterBindingAttribute
    {
        public override HttpParameterBinding GetBinding(HttpParameterDescriptor Parameter)
        {
            return new XmlParameterBinding(Parameter);
        }
    }

    public class XmlParameterBinding : HttpParameterBinding
    {
        public XmlParameterBinding(HttpParameterDescriptor Descriptor) : base(Descriptor)
        {
        }

        public override Task ExecuteBindingAsync(ModelMetadataProvider MetadataProvider, HttpActionContext ActionContext, CancellationToken CancellationToken)
        {
            return ActionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ContinueWith(Task =>
            {
                var Binding = ActionContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionBinding;
                var Type = Binding.ParameterBindings[0].Descriptor.ParameterType;

                XmlSerializer Serializer = new XmlSerializer(Type);

                using (StringReader Reader = new StringReader(Task.Result))
                    SetValue(ActionContext, Serializer.Deserialize(Reader));
            });
        }

        public override bool WillReadBody => true;
    }
}
```